# Submit button only in one column of my table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Okay so this is probably a fairly easy solution but I can't seem to find any answers anywhere else, I want my submit button on the far right column (Accept/Decline), but when I try and position it somewhere else it wont do it...

The CSS:

```
#table2 {
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 150px;
width:680px;
}
```

The Table: (I've removed a lot of code when I put it on here, if you want anymore of my code, please ask)
`    
        
            
                Employee name
                Holiday Start Date
                Holiday End Date
                No. Days
                Reason
                Accept/Decline

```
        <tr>
            <td><%response.Write(objDBRS(0))%></td>
            <td><%response.Write(formatdatetime(objDBRS(1)))%></td>
            <td><%response.Write(formatdatetime(objDBRS(2)))%></td>
            <td><%response.Write((objDBRS(3)))%></td>
            <td><%response.Write((objDBRS(5)))%></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radio<%=a%>" />
                <input type="radio" name="radio<%=a%>" />
            </td>


            </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is automaticaly placed on the left html:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
```

Give it a colspan 6 then you can move it to the right by using float in CSS or position with CSS